# Springboot 3.2 Jackson Parsing error while webclient Call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I am using springboot 3.1.4, Java 17 and jackson 2.15.0. I have to migrate a project from springboot 2.7 to springboot 3.1.4. Earlier the webclient call was working fine, but after migrating to springboot 3.1.4, API response from webclient while jackson parsing is giving error.

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.7.21</kotlin.version>
       <springdoc.openapi.version>2.2.0</springdoc.openapi.version>
        <swagger-annotations.version>2.2.0</swagger-annotations.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <apache.poi.version>5.2.3</apache.poi.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

While calling another service from webclient, jackson is giving error while parsing webclient response.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createNonBlockingByteBufferParser()'
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2Tokenizer.tokenize(Jackson2Tokenizer.java:251)
```

Comment: Remove `jackson-core` as a dependency, remove the `version` tag from the kotlin one. This is assuming you have `spring-boot-starter-webflux` as a dependency.

Comment: I did as   you mentioned @M.Deinum, still facing the same issue. I have spring-boot-starter-webflux

Comment: Please add all your dependencies (or your full `pom.xml`) to the question. The fact that you had these in there makes me wonder what else you have. Also be aware that Spring BOot 3.2 is not a production release yet but still under development!.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have switched to springboot 3.1.4 and added all dependencies i am using in the question

Comment: Do you have a `dependencyManagement` section? Also I believe the `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` isn't compatible with Spring Boot 3.x and pulls in older dependencies.

Comment: Since you haven't shown your full POM, I'm skeptical about which version of jackson-core is being used in your project. I recommend you double check that you are using Jackson 2.15.0. According to the source, `createNonBlockingByteBufferParser()` should exist: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/jackson-core-2.15.0/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.java#L1323 . This method was added in jackson-core 2.14.0, so I suspect your version is older.